# Instant write buffer to stdout

Tags: c, buffer

Is possible to write a large block of text into stdout all at once.

For instance, I get a 50kb text file and put it into story.txt. I am curious if I can dump the contents of this file into stdout without the user noticing any text slowly coming in. One moment there is no text, next the whole buffer is flushed into stdout.

I was trying to do it with the following code but no matter what buffering mode I set it didn't manage to write the file all at once, only in parts.

```
/* dumps a lot of text at once */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

char story[100000];
char buffer[100000];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *handle = fopen("coolstory.txt", "r");
    size_t n = fread(&story[0], 1, 100000, handle);
    fclose(handle);

    /* try to flush all at once... */
    fclose(stdout);
    freopen("/dev/tty", "w", stdout);
    setvbuf(stdout, &buffer[0], _IOFBF, 100000);
    fwrite(story, n, 1, stdout);
    fflush(stdout);

    printf("\nread %u bytes.\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

The reopen part was me wondering if setvbuf/flush would behave differently if I called them right after the stdout was opened. Unfortunately it did nothing.

I just want to know whether it is possible, and if not, why.

Comment: Console I/O is generally slow *because* it needs to be rendered and visible to the user. You can get much faster writes to `stdout` if it is redirected to a file.

Comment: So stdout by design has to write out every single character when it is being flushed? It seems to do it in blocks sometimes, but maybe I am mistaken.

Comment: @Dmitry, try `$ cat /usr/include/stdio.h`. On my machine it's roughly 30KiB and looks like it finishes in ~5 frames at 144Hz. I don't think you'll have much trouble with 50KiB.

Comment: C spec says "The setvbuf function may be used only after the stream pointed to by stream has been associated with an open file and before any other operation (other than an unsuccessful call to setvbuf) is performed on the stream" --> so `fclose(stdout); freopen()` may violate that?  IDK.

Comment: @chux that's actually why I did that experiment.

Comment: IMO, since code is attempting to do something that strays outside the C specification, it is undefined behavior.  It may "work" as desired on your platform/compiler today, but not in another system tomorrow. Good luck in your investigation.

Comment: I just want to be sure there is no specification.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on ubuntu linux 14.04.

Note: it is usually a bad idea to #include header files that are not used.

I ran this version of the code:

```
/* dumps a lot of text at once */
//#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <fcntl.h>
//#include <string.h>

char story[100000];


int main( void )
{
    FILE *handle = fopen("value_chainLength.txt", "r");
    size_t n = fread(story, 1, 100000, handle);
    fclose(handle);


    fwrite(story, n, 1, stdout);
    fflush(stdout);

    printf("\nread %lu bytes.\n", (long unsigned)n);

    return 0;
}
```

on a 46550749 byte text file

The output was done on a terminal almost as fast as I could press and release the 'enter' key.

the last line output was:

```
read 100000 bytes.
```

I did notice ever so slight a hesitation before printing the last line, all the lines before that point were practically instantaneous.

Comment: For the purpose of this experiment, I do not care much for "practically instantaneous". I want only the final screen to be drawn, and all at once. That is, similar to double buffering. I think curses can do this but I was wondering if standard c could, or at least with help of libc terminal functions.